# Split single row into multiple row based on no of sets in python

Tags: pandas, numpy, csv

I'm trying to split a record containing 15 variables into set of 5 records with first record containing 3 variables data & remaining 12 variables having null values, 2nd record containing 6 variables & remaining 9 variables having null values & 3rd record containing 9 variables & remaining 6 variables null values.

each of the record will have class variable same.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out a python program to do this on about 149 record dataset.

Can somebody please help.

Thanks,
N

Comment: Please share a sample input with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: @MayankPorwal.. image added for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broadcasting to mask - it means compare array created by `np.arange` by length of index with array created with length of columns divide by integers divisions by `3` for triples:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 15))
        .rename(columns=lambda x: f'V{x+1}')
        .assign(Class = [0,1,1,0]))
print (df)
         V1        V2        V3        V4  ...       V13       V14       V15  Class
0  0.986277  0.873392  0.509746  0.271836  ...  0.736325  0.355663  0.341093      0
1  0.666803  0.217101  0.561427  0.124179  ...  0.456119  0.155851  0.476049      1
2  0.169702  0.896258  0.373394  0.379693  ...  0.763921  0.919691  0.070573      1
3  0.156165  0.636894  0.555696  0.191929  ...  0.936032  0.803028  0.697305      0

[4 rows x 16 columns]
```

---

```
N = 15
new_rows = N // 3
df1 = df.iloc[:, :N]
mask = np.arange(new_rows)[:, None] >= np.arange(len(df1.columns)) // 3

repeated = np.tile(df1.to_numpy(), new_rows).reshape(new_rows * len(df.index), -1)
mask = np.tile(mask, (len(df1.index), 1))

arr = np.where(mask, repeated, np.nan)

df1 = (pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns[:N])
         .assign(Class = np.repeat(df['Class'].to_numpy(), new_rows)))
```

---

```
print (df1)

          V1        V2        V3        V4  ...       V13       V14       V15  Class
0   0.986277  0.873392  0.509746       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      0
1   0.986277  0.873392  0.509746  0.271836  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      0
2   0.986277  0.873392  0.509746  0.271836  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      0
3   0.986277  0.873392  0.509746  0.271836  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      0
4   0.986277  0.873392  0.509746  0.271836  ...  0.736325  0.355663  0.341093      0
5   0.666803  0.217101  0.561427       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      1
6   0.666803  0.217101  0.561427  0.124179  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      1
7   0.666803  0.217101  0.561427  0.124179  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      1
8   0.666803  0.217101  0.561427  0.124179  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      1
9   0.666803  0.217101  0.561427  0.124179  ...  0.456119  0.155851  0.476049      1
10  0.169702  0.896258  0.373394       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      1
11  0.169702  0.896258  0.373394  0.379693  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      1
12  0.169702  0.896258  0.373394  0.379693  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      1
13  0.169702  0.896258  0.373394  0.379693  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      1
14  0.169702  0.896258  0.373394  0.379693  ...  0.763921  0.919691  0.070573      1
15  0.156165  0.636894  0.555696       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      0
16  0.156165  0.636894  0.555696  0.191929  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      0
17  0.156165  0.636894  0.555696  0.191929  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      0
18  0.156165  0.636894  0.555696  0.191929  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN      0
19  0.156165  0.636894  0.555696  0.191929  ...  0.936032  0.803028  0.697305      0

[20 rows x 16 columns]
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer but seems like your code work only for single record. I wanted to apply this concept on each record of df containing 149 unique records with 3 sets per record for spliting

Comment: @Naseer - Can you test now? `N` is necessary change by number of columns.

Comment: Looks like it is working as expected. Thanks Jezrael for help. I have used lot of for loops with breaks, confusing code. Thanks again!

Comment: @Naseer - Sure, good idea. I try create the most general solution, so add `N` - only necessary N is divisable by `3` like `3,9,15, 99, 150` ... ;)

Comment: can you suggest, where can i make changes in code to assign set with different variables no. like first set contains 3, 2nd set contains 5, 3rd set contains 4, 4th set contains 3 ?

Comment: @Naseer - I think the best is create new question, if different values per each groups I guess need different soluion.

Comment: added here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65070079/split-multiple-row-based-on-no-of-sets-no-of-variables-in-python appreciate your help.